# substitutions in vi editor

Tags: regular-expression, vim, vi, variable-substitution

I have file called `foo.txt`. This file contains values:

```
abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

I would like to get an output like this

```
abc abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1 abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2 bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

Same value/text has to appear before original value/text. How to achieve this using regular expressions?

```
%s/^[a-z_-]*./\1/g
```

Above expression I used but I got wrong output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capture groups [`:help /\(`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%28) let you store what's matched by the pattern inside  `\(...\)`; you can then reference the match (via `\1` for the first group, `\2`, and so on) in the replacement (or even afterwards in the pattern itself).

One approach (there are many) to your problem is to capture the filename before the `.tar.gz` extension. In the replacement, put the capture (`\1`), a space, then the original text (`\0`, or `&`):

```
:%substitute/\(.*\)\.tar\.gz$/\1 &/
```

Alternatively, you can just match the stuff before the extension (ending the match with `\ze`), and then duplicate that:

```
:%substitute/.*\ze\.tar\.gz$/& &/
```

#### Problems with your attempt

- You used the backreference `\1`, but never captured anything.
- The `[a-z_-]` does not match a literal `.`, but this appears in your example.
- No escaping of the final `.` (as `\.`); it would match any character.
- No duplication in the replacement part; you effectively removed text instead of adding.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always .tar.gz to be removed, then:

```
%s/^\(.*\).tar.gz/\1 \1.tar.gz/g
```

Answer (score 0):

filename: testt

```
abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

command

```
sed "s/[a-z]\{3\}\.\{0,1\}-\{0,2\}\.\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}\.\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}/& &/" test| sed "/[a-z]\{3\}\. /s/\.//1"
```

output

```
abc abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1 abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2 bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Spinning off on [the currently accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470258/116858), if the string suffix possibly changes from `.tar.gz` to some other `.xxx.yyy`-like string, the following would accept any two strings `xxx` and `yyy`:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)\(\..*\)\{2\}$/\1 &/' foo.txt
abc abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1 abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2 bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

This can obviously also also be used in `vi` as `:%s/\(.*\)\(\..*\)\{2\}$/\1 &/`.

Or, using extended regular expressions with a `sed` that understands `-E`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)(\..*){2}$/\1 &/' foo.txt
abc abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1 abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2 bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

The `{2}` here indicates the matching of a suffix of exactly two dot-delimited substrings.

---

```
$ rev foo.txt | cut -d . -f 3- | rev | paste - foo.txt
abc     abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1 abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2 bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

This doesn't use regular expressions, but removes the `.tar.gz` suffix from what I assume are filenames and then pastes the original data in as a second column.

The suffix strings are removed by means of reversing the lines and then keeping all dot-delimited fields from the 3rd field onward. Reversing this again has the effect of cutting off the last two dot-delimited filename components.

The final output is tab-delimited, but you can make it space-delimited as in the question by replacing the last `paste` step with  `paste -d ' ' - foo.txt`.

---

In a similar manner as above, but using the `basename` utility to cut off the `.tar.gz` filename suffixes:

```
$ xargs -I {} basename {} .tar.gz <foo.txt | paste - foo.txt
abc     abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1 abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2 bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score -2):

Does it have to be `vi`?

If not, this might do what you want (using GNU `xargs`).

```
cat foo.txt | xargs -i basename {} .tar.gz | xargs -i echo {} {}.tar.gz
```

where `foo.txt` is your file.

Update.

```
$ cat foo.txt
abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2.tar.gz


$ cat foo.txt | xargs -i basename {} .tar.gz | xargs -i echo {} {}.tar.gz
abc abc.tar.gz
abc.1.1 abc.1.1.tar.gz
bca-1.2 bca-1.2.tar.gz
```

You don't get it as above?

Comment: `abc.tar.gz.tar.gzabc.tar.gz.tar.gz.tar.gz` **output** was like that

Comment: space was not applied correctly, it works

Comment: Bloody hell...I got negged twice... was just trying to help :-) and it worked too.